# How can I track the reason why an ASP.NET Session times out?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to track down an issue on an ASP.NET v3.5 application where the `HttpSession` times out before its (default) 20 minutes. We're seeing behaviour where the session is lost only a few minutes into a session, at random and with no discernible cause such as unhandled exceptions. As far as I can tell, the ASP.NET worker process is not dying, otherwise that would have explained the dropped session.

What approach should I use to monitor when the session is dropped? Is there some event I can listen to, or some other hook in the `System.Web` namespace?

Also, can someone confirm that the countdown to expiration is reset by web activity? That is, the session's lifetime gets reset to the (default) 20 minutes each time the web client makes an HTTP GET or POST?

Comment: How do you know that the process is not dying?

Comment: Just a longshot...are you using Forms Authentication? Are you sure it is the session, and not the authentication cookie that times out? I was faced with this problem once and it was solved by simply setting the timeout for the authentication cookie to twice the value of the session time out.

Comment: @Stilgar: I've written a program that polls the task list for the process ID's of the IIS worker processes. The process IDs remain unchanged across session drops.

Comment: @Ozzy: the problem manifests itself even when unauthenticated users are browsing our site.

Comment: Are the application running on a stand alone IIS with no other applications? Just thinking that maybe some other app are messing with your Session State

Comment: There is a SQL Server on the same machine, but neither IIS nor SQL Server is experiencing too heavy a load.

Comment: @John the Application Pool can be recycled within the same process. Are all sessions dropped or only a single one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [Session_OnEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx) event you can use.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach. I can log Session_OnEnd calls and their associated call stacks and hope that the session drops still occur.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the limits configured for the IIS. There are a few of them to limit CPU, Network usage etc. If this happens it will write all the logging to the Event Log if closing a session.

And on your second question the countdown timer for a session in IIS is rested at every request.

Update:
Check this one out..
http://bluedragon.blog-city.com/lost_sessions_webgardens_sessionstate.htm

Talking about setting the max number of processes to higher than 1.

Cheers,
Stefan